# Join one table twice in mysql linq query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join

```
public IEnumerable<TimesheetModel> GetTicketsInProgressByUserId(int id){
    var query = (from workLogList in DataContext.tblWorkLogs
                 join tickets in DataContext.tblTickets on workLogList.TicketId equals tickets.TicketId into wlWithtickets 
                 from worklog in wlWithtickets.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join project in DataContext.tblProjects on worklog.ProjectId equals project.ProjectId into worklogfull
                 from list in worklogfull.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join prnames in DataContext.tblProjects on workLogList.ProjectId equals prnames.ProjectId into table
                 from table1 in table.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where workLogList.AccountId == id 
                 group workLogList by workLogList.WorkDate.Date into data
                 select new TimesheetModel {
                     TaskDate = data.Key,
                     TimesheetList = data.Select(x => new TimesheetListModel()
                     {
                         ProjectId = x.tblTicket != null ? x.tblTicket.tblProject.ProjectId : x.ProjectId,
                         ProjectName = x.tblTicket != null ? x.tblTicket.tblProject.Name : null,
                         Date = x.WorkDate,
                         TimeWorked = x.TimeWorked,
                         Note = x.Note,
                         Task = x.tblTicket != null ? "#" + x.tblTicket.TicketId + " : " + x.tblTicket.Title :  x.TaskTitle
                     }).ToList()
                 });
    return query;
}
```

I have table `tblWorklogs` with fields `ticketId` and `projectId` and other. For `ticketId` I join `tblTickets` where `ticketId` in `tblWorklogs` equals `ticketId` in `tblTickets`, and in `tblTickets` I also have `projectId` for that I joining `tblProjects` to take `projectId` and `projectName`. But in my `tblWorklogs` field `ticketId` can be `null` and I need to join `tblProjects` via `projectId` equals `tblProjects.projectId` and take project Id and Name. How I can do joining one table twice in this query?

Comment: can you use `projectId` from `tblWorklogs` instead of `tblTickets`?

Comment: Don't join, use navigation properties.